# "View on site" button is linked to an unwanted page

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

Why "view on site" linked to an unwanted page? Can I disable it?

Answer (score 4):

View on site determines the URL to link to by checking the `Sites` app and adding the model's `get_absolute_url()` method on the end of it.

Answer (score 3):

[See the django-docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) You can overwrite the admin-templates or [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911887/how-can-i-get-the-django-admins-view-on-site-link-to-work/911929), how to use it

Answer (score 1):

the easiest and cleanest way is to set `admin.site.site_url = None` in your root urls.py

it works since django 1.8,
[here is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes)

Comment: or one can do it in admin.py

Answer (score -4):

sudo vi /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin$/change_from.html.

in this file comment out the if condition

{% if has_absolute_url %}

{% trans "View on site" %}

{% endif%}

then view on site will never appear

Comment: Editing core files should be LAST resort, if it should be used at all!

Comment: Don't edit files directly in the packages. Your changes will never (automatically) make it to the production environment, your coworker, etc.

Comment: alternatively, you can copy this template file to your local project template folder and edit it