# Django: Remove "view on site" button in the admin User change form

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

get_absolute_url() method is cool, but in some cases is not needed. django.contrib.auth.models.User has it set by default, this cause my projects to have a broken link in the admin.

How can I prevent that from happening?

In one of my old projects I set a custom template in which I removed the html of the button, it doesn't sound like a good solution that would scale though. Anything better?

Comment: What do you mean 'scale'? Are you worried about what happens when you want to do this on millions of different models? Template overriding is exactly the solution that I would use for this.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964868/view-on-site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done, per model, as of django 1.7.

```
# myapp/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    view_on_site = False

admin.site.register(MyModel,MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: this is the more recent best answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you click on Django 1.7 link, the site will tell you that "Its an insecure version of Django that is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a newer release!"

For Django 1.9, following solution works fine as mentioned in the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes)

in myapp/admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # Disable View on Site link on admin page
    site_url = None
```

Comment: this is the more recent best answer, I'm doing this in my more recent projects.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of monkey patching you can hide the button on the client side using JavaScript. The HTML of the view on site button looks like this:

```
<li><a href="/admin/r/4/2/" class="viewsitelink">View on site</a></li>
```

If you just hide the anchor tag you will get part of the round button appearing as that is applied on the li tag. Now unfortunately there is no easy way to use css to select that specific li tag since it doesn't have a class, name or id on it. So we can use jquery which gives you more control on your selectors. Put the following in your static folder. For example in the location static/admin/user_change_form.js

```
django.jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $(".viewsitelink").parent().css('display', 'none')
});
```

Your admin.py could then look something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.admin import site

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ['admin/user_change_form.js']

site.unregister(User)
site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**UPDATE**

A feature was added in Django 1.7 [ModelAdmin.view_on_site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.view_on_site) which lets you not display the “View on site” link.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I came across it when I had to do the same thing.

A better solution would be to monkey patch it in an `accounts/admin.py` file when you have `accounts` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
# We don't want a broken View on Site link.  Thanks for that, contrib.auth!
del User.get_absolute_url
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3):

Django 2.0 above you can add in default admin

```
admin.site.site_url = None
```

Above trick worked for me very well.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, I have a `monkey_patch` app at the bottom of my `INSTALLED_APPS` which modifies the built in django contrib apps in ways I haven't found better ways to modify such as username length, default admin forms, `__unicode__`, etc.

Just watch your back when you upgrade django / in general.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
del User.get_absolute_url
```

Comment: i accept this answer but i'm not so keen on using it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Django 1.4 and Marwan Alsabbagh's solution worked fine for me. Although, when opening/refreshing User change form there was a short blink. That is because JQuery hides this button only when page is loaded.

To solve this minor issue I used CSS to hide the whole .change-form block. After page is loaded this block's visibility is restored by means of JQuery. So, my code looks like this:

admin.py:

```
class Media:
    js = ['js/admin/user_change_form.js']
    css = {'all': ('css/admin/user_change_form.css',)}
```

...static/css/admin/user_change_form.css

```
.change-form {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

...static/js/admin/user_change_form.js

```
/* Do not show 'View on site' button in User change form */
django.jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $(".viewsitelink").parent().css('display', 'none')
    /* restore visibility of the page (hidden in css to avoid blinking) */
    $(".change-form").css('visibility', 'visible')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use
**admin.site.site_url = "your url here"**
in url.py of ur main app to modify the **"visit site"** on django page
and
for **"view_on_site" removal**
use
**view_on_site = False** in ur class with display_list for

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app config (`apps.py`) do this:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        admin.site.site_url = None
```

Works in Django 4.0 as well.